# Can i have a Query within a Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm new to SQL. I may not be using the proper terms or syntax.  The goal behind the code is that if a city's population decreases by more than 10% then that city's continent's population decreases by 5%.  I was trying to make the link between a city's pop decline to its continent by using a nested query.  Is that the right way to go?

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER PopAdjustment 
AFTER UPDATE
ON City 
FOR EACH ROW 
IF (City.NEW_Population / City.Population) =  < .9   
THEN
SELECT City.Name, Country.Continent FROM Country JOIN Country ON  City.CountryCode = Country.Code 
WHERE City.NEW_Population / City.Population  =  < .9 
SET Country.Continent = (Country.Continent * 0.95) ; 
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You are not allowed to return a result set (ie select other than select into) from a trigger

Comment: You asked this 2 days ago . You would have a better chance of getting an answer if you added sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically and conceptually there is a lot wrong with this trigger. I advise you to read the manual. But to help clarify please also study this

```
drop table if exists city,country;
create table city(name varchar(10), population int, countrycode int);
create table country(code int primary key,continent int);
insert into city values('aaa',100,1);
insert into country values(1,100);

drop trigger if exists t;
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER t 
AFTER UPDATE
ON City 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
 IF (NEW.Population / old.Population) <= .9   THEN
    update country
        SET Country.Continent = Country.Continent * 0.95 
        where country.code = new.countrycode; 
 END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
update city
    set population = 80
    where city.name = 'aaa';

select * from city;
select * from country;
+------+------------+-------------+
| name | population | countrycode |
+------+------------+-------------+
| aaa  |         80 |           1 |
+------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```